# relationship between commutative matrix's eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

i am interested  if there is some relationship between eigenvalues of commutative matrices?or for any two matrix $A$ and $B$,we have following equation

$A*B=B*A$

for example

```
A=[1 2;3 4]

A =

     1     2
     3     4
```

and second matrix

```
B=[7 10; 15 22]

B =

     7    10
    15    22
```

we have

```
A*B

ans =

    37    54
    81   118
```

and

```
B*A

ans =

    37    54
    81   118
```

now i have  several questions,just in simple please help me to clarify it,what is relationship between eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$?or  between   $A*B$ and   $A$?or between product of these two matrix and matrix $B$?as i know for some given two matrices

$e^{A+B}=e^{A}*e^{B}$

when $A*B=B*A$

because we can represent matrix exponential  for diagonalisable matrix using  eigenvalues,can we see some relationship between commute matrices?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commuting matrices have the same set of non zero eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity).

This is because commuting set of matrices are [simultaneously trianguralizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneously_triangularizable#Simultaneous_triangularisability). The eigenvalues of an upper triangular matrix are the diagonal elements. Eigenvalues of $AB$ are just the product of eigenvalues of $A$ with those of $B$.

Comment: but different value right? how can i understand same set of non zero eigenvalues?

Comment: Non zero eigenvalues are the same for $AB$ and $BA$. The eigenvalues are the products of eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$. For example if $A$ has an eigenvalue 2, and $B$ has an eigenvalue $4$, then $AB$ has an eigenvalue $8$, and so on. Hope that helps.

Comment: and does linear combination of commute matrices would be also commute with original matrices??

Comment: Yes :). Even more is true. If $P,Q$ are polynomials, and $AB=BA$ then $P(A)Q(B)=Q(B)P(A)$.

Comment: vau ,it is  very nice,thanks very much

Comment: The first sentence is very wrong. Did you mean to say _eigenvectors_ (which are nonzero by definition)? Even then, the sets are not always the same.